# Why is there a parse exception in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

```
AddLocationForm:

<AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:orientation:"vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
        Button:
            text: "Search"
        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
```

I have weather.kv file like the above one but I am getting an error as below

kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "C:\programming\projects\scripts\kivy\FirstApp\weather.kv", line 3:

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ParserException - Invalid data after declaration

```
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 575, in parse_level
     'Invalid data after declaration')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File ".../weather.kv", line 3:
 ...
       1:AddLocationForm:
       2:
 >>    3:<AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:orientation:"vertical"
       4:    BoxLayout:
       5:        TextInput:
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration
```

## Explanation

You are encountering the following *ParserException* because when your kv file is parsed, it is expecting nothing after the class rule declartion, ***<AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:*** but it found ***orientation: "vertical"***

[Programming Guide » Kv language » Rule context](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

> A class rule, declared by the name of a widget class between ***< >*** and
>   followed by ***:***, defines how any instance of that class will be
>   graphically represented:

## Solution

### weather.kv

```
AddLocationForm:

<AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>
    orientation: "vertical"
    TextInput:
    Button:
        text: "Search"
    Button:
        text: "Current Location"
```

## Output

[image]